# Change bitmap color at runtime in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, bitmap

i develop in WPF. I have a black bitmap and i want to change color to white at runtime !

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [WriteableBitmapExtensions](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) it's pretty easy.

```
using WriteableBitmapEx;

...

myBitmap.Clear(System.Windows.Media.Colors.White);
```